# Why do we use LDD technique in IC fabrication technology?

Tags: integrated-circuit, semiconductors, vlsi, silicon, microfabrication

Why do we use LDD(lightly doped drain) in IC fabrication technology?

In the "*silicon VLSI technology*" book, was mentioned that this is in order to create a voltage drop in drain region. So don't you think this force the supply voltage greater?

Comment: Not a complete answer because I can't fully explain the mechanisms (my coworker does the semiconductor design; I just test it), but it increases the blocking voltage of the device by spreading out the electric field over a larger volume.

Answer (score 2):

A Low Doped Drain (LDD) region is basically what it sounds like. You add an extension to the (highly) doped drain that is low doped. This extension reduces the electric field at the pinchoff region. Reducing the electric field strength helps reduce short channel effects and hot electron effects. It can also increase the breakdown voltage.